# POSTFIX sending mail through Office 365?

Tags: postfix, microsoft-office-365

I have my conf file like this:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = data-0
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, data-0, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.office365.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
# enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication.
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption
smtp_use_tls = yes
# where to find CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Thing i did 
i followed this link https://www.onceuponanipsum.com/relay-mail-with-office-365-and-postfix/

my errors are:

```
May 19 11:14:05 data-2 postfix/smtp[23560]: 359DA41830: to=<abc@xyz.com>, relay=smtp.office365.com[40.101.50.194]:587, delay=1616, delays=1498/0.02/118/0, dsn=4.7.3, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; server smtp.office365.com[40.101.50.194] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [HE1PR0902CA0020.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com])
```

How can i avoid it? How can i add "Exchange Users" to the "Permission Group"?

Thanks

Comment: Try this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/906f235a-9979-43de-944f-d9adac0385c5/535-573-authentication-unsuccessful?forum=exchange2010

Comment: Recommended reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4

Comment: Thanks@blaughw i had used the link that you had suggested and used the option 1 for my requirement .First it had shown `Network Unreachable` when i kept `inet_protocols = all` then when i modified it to `inet_protocols = ipv4` it is showing the same error that i kept in my question.